# Printing from Chromium Embedded Framework 3

Tags: delphi, chromium, chromium-embedded, tchromium

In an older DCEF (v1) project, I used this line to print:

```
  Chromium1.Browser.MainFrame.Print;
```

I'm now working with DCEF3 in a Delphi 2010 project. I know earlier versions of CEF3 didn't print, but is there a way to do this now? So far no where that I've looked has shown how. Thanks.

Comment: `Chromium1.Browser.Host.Print;`?

Comment: Seems to work. Thanks

Comment: It should :) DCEF3 internally calls this [Print](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/CefBrowserHost.html#Print()) method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In DCEF3 it is:

```
Chromium1.Browser.Host.Print;
```

In CEF3, the [**Print**](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/CefBrowserHost.html#Print()) method has been moved to the [**CefBrowserHost**](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/CefBrowserHost.html) class, which is accessible by the above code line in DCEF3.